# destroy admin session resulting in http get request rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rails-admin

My Rails 4 application has an User and and Admin model.

I have implemented devise for the Admin model which was created via rails_admin gem. The problem occurs when I attempt to logout: the app redirects in an unexpected page and logs show that GET requests keep being made, instead of DELETE ones.

Following research I have ensured that the logout link has the delete method specified as below

<%= link_to "Admin logout", destroy_admin_session_path, :method => :delete %>

in devise.rb the sign out is specified via delete
    config.sign_out_via = :delete

The routes are as follow

```
Mvc::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  devise_for :admins
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
root "users#index"
end
```

I am perfectly able to login without issue, but when the logout request is rendered in the browser into /admins/sign_out the session is still active, and the page still displays the admin dashboard. Interestingly the flash message shows 'Model 'S' could not be found' and I am really puzzled by what the logs shows

```
Started GET "/admins/sign_out" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-03 23:10:50 +0000
Processing by RailsAdmin::MainController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"model_name"=>"s", "id"=>"sign_out"}
[RailsAdmin] Could not load model S, assuming model is non existing. (uninitialized constant S)


Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.1'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby'
gem 'devise'
gem 'rails_admin'


group :assets do
 gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0' 
 gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
 gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

end

group :doc do

 gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :development do
 gem 'better_errors', '~> 2.0.0'
end
```

What I would like to achieve is that when the logout is executed, the admin session is destroyed and the admin is redirected to the root_path. I note that I currently only have the application and user controller and no session controller. From what I understand the devise engine should bring session management out of the box. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: The :method => :delete functionality comes from jquery_ujs.  Is that present in your project?  You may need to add //= require jquery_ujs to your application.js file

Comment: RailsAdmin is hijacking your route from Devise, and then because it doesn't recognize `/admins/sign_out` it is interpreting it as `/admins/:id`, routing to the Show method, and trying to match a model with an id of "sign_out". You'll need to find a way to disentangle RailsAdmin and Devise to get the routes working the way you need them to.

Comment: Thanks Joseph that makes sense, I'll keep digging in this direction.

Answer (score -1):

It's seems that you aren't using the application layout file.
So try to add the following snippet of code to the html file

```html
<head>
  <title>Training</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```